torch.jit.script_method error when implementing a custom GRU
The code is following:
@jit.script_method
    def forward(self, inputs, mask=None, training=None, initial_state=None):
        # s3 = time.time()
        if initial_state is None:
            batch_size = inputs.size(0)
            initial_state = [
                torch.zeros(batch_size, self.units, device=inputs.device),
                torch.ones(batch_size, 1, device=inputs.device),
                torch.zeros(batch_size, 1, device=inputs.device)
            ]

        forward_outputs = []
        forward_upgates = []
        states = initial_state
        print(f'Initial states type: {type(states)}')
        # s4 = time.time()
        for t in range(inputs.size(1)):
            output, states = self.cell(inputs[:, t, :], states)
            print(f'States after cell call type: {type(states)}')

all the output of print function is class list,but still face the error below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\CRNDenoise\model\CRN_Denoise\test.py", line 44, in <module>
    model = SkipGRU(hidden_size, channel, bidirectional=False, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\torch\jit\_script.py", line 286, in init_then_script
    ] = torch.jit._recursive.create_script_module(self, make_stubs, share_types=not added_methods_in_init)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\torch\jit\_recursive.py", line 454, in create_script_module
    return create_script_module_impl(nn_module, concrete_type, stubs_fn)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\torch\jit\_recursive.py", line 520, in create_script_module_impl
    create_methods_and_properties_from_stubs(concrete_type, method_stubs, property_stubs)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\torch\jit\_recursive.py", line 371, in create_methods_and_properties_from_stubs
    concrete_type._create_methods_and_properties(property_defs, property_rcbs, method_defs, method_rcbs, method_defaults)
RuntimeError: 
Variable 'states' previously had type Tensor (inferred) but is now being assigned to a value of type List[Tensor]
:
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\CRNDenoise\model\CRN_Denoise\skip_gru.py", line 177
        # s4 = time.time()
        for t in range(inputs.size(1)):
            output, states = self.cell(inputs[:, t, :], states)
                    ~~~~~~ <--- HERE
            # print(f'States after cell call type: {type(states)}')
            forward_outputs.append(output[0])

how to fix that? also tried the funtion torch.jit.script(model),but failed
